# Actual requirements for iTunes Match?

Tags: itunes, music, apple-music, itunes-match, system-requirements

I decided that I want to sign up for iTunes Match.  But I'm not sure how I can, or even if I can.

I visited the "[Subscribe to iTunes Match](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204146)" page on the Apple Support site  and it says, "To subscribe to iTunes Match, update your Mac to the latest version of macOS."

Well, in our household there are 5 Macs.  The newest one is from 2016.  So none of these machines will run the latest version of macOS, which right now is macOS Ventura.

So my questions are:

- Is it actually true that one cannot sign up for iTunes Match on any Mac running anything earlier than macOS 13?  That seems pretty extreme to me.
- Suppose I borrow (or even buy) a new Mac that *will* run macOS 13, and then use that to sign up for iTunes Match by following the instructions on the support page.  Will I then be able to use iTunes Match or any of its features on any of my other, older Macs?  (The Apple support page isn't clear on what version of macOS is required to actually *use* iTunes Match.)  Certainly, some of my older machines run older versions of iTunes and those seem to be aware that iTunes Match is a thing.  But if I signed up on a newer machine, would those older machines with older iTunes versions actually work fine (or at all) with iTunes Match?

In short, I am *suspicious* of Apple's stated requirements to *sign up* for iTunes Match, and I am *unable to find* any stated requirements for *using* iTunes Match.

If anyone can provide some definitive answers on this, that would be awesome.  Many thanks!

Comment: Apple likes to "restrict" some features to only new versions of macOS. It's an observed fact. Apple's article on it is pretty clear: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204146 . On a Mac use the music.app and look for the iTunes Store and the link to iTunes match. If you don't see it your Mac needs a newer version of macOS. And while I have never *used* iTunes match I would bet that all Macs wanting to participate need to be running a similar, compatible, version of macOS. And it is easy and free to find out: update to the latest version of macOS and follow the instructions at that link.

Comment: @SteveChambers: Yep, I agree.  If I had a different Mac running each version of macOS, I could fire up Apple Music on each one and discover the answer to _half_ of my question, as to what OS is really required to sign up.  As for the second half, I agree that your “bet” sounds about right.  But I'm hoping someone may know more and can contribute an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's common practice for Apple to suggest updating iOS/macOS to the latest version before carrying out any process as it's a common troubleshooting step if something goes wrong.

However, iTunes Match was released in 2011 in iTunes 10.5.1. The article you link to was written in 2021 before Ventura was released. It should be possible to sign up for iTunes Match wherever it shows as available on the macOS you are using at the moment.